# Are the libraries different that is building from android-ndk in different platform

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to release my SDK. but I have no idea Do I have some unknown problems if I compile the .so from different platforms (Mac or Window using same ndk version).

I think it is same between different platforms but I didn't have windows platform to confirm.
So Are the libraries different build from different platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bluntly, you should not believe that compilers produce the same code on the same input deterministically. Many do, but many do not. This is especially true when using optimization. (This situation is improving now the problem is recognized). The consequence of this is no matter what you build on you must only release the exact binary you have tested.

That said, you can totally build with the NDK on multiple platforms. Many of the large games studios use Windows and Macs for development, and production builds are done on Linux continuous integration systems, so this is done in practice all the time. You are far more likely to run into trouble with any extra tooling you have than the ndk itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely mix Android binaries built on Mac and Windows, but please make sure you use the same NDK release and same parameters (most notably, same APP_STL).

You can send your native libraries built on Mac to Java developers who work on Windows. They don't even need NDK and don't care which release you were using (as long as it works).